# In the future how many Buddhas will be born?

Tags: the-buddha, buddhas

In our world, (Earth) there were 28 Buddha born with Gautama Buddha. Some people say that Maitreya Buddha is the 29th & last Buddha. My question is, in the future how many Buddhas will born.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinite number into the past and infinite number to the future.

28 are the immediate preceding our Buddha. Maitreya will be the next.

Comment: @Bhumishu米殊 I recommend you post that as a separate/new answer, instead of as a comment.

Comment: I recomment ur editing it's Theravadist teaching. Mahayana teaches there will be in total for this Great Kalpa called 賢劫 (Noble Kalpa?) 1000 Buddhas, Maitreya is the 5th after our Buddha Shkyamuni. The last one, 1000th is 樓至佛 (presently cultivating as Bodhisattva Veda [?]). These Buddhas' accounts were recorded in 《千佛因緣經》, translated by Kumarajiva. Also, the OP's "Earth" connotation is of question. Buddhist cosmology allowed the beings to live is encompassing beyond Earth.

Comment: Thx @ChrisW am not interested to answer but concerned Suminda didn't state its Theravadist. However to backup my editing recommendation I hv to state what I learnt from different School. Suminda may incl. in his answer if he finds fitted.

Comment: @Bhumishu米殊 I expect that Suminda's answer is based on the doctrine that he knows/has read. I don't think you should expect him to answer based on Mahayana doctrine (if that's different); if you think this question should be answered based on Mahayana doctrine too, perhaps you could post your comment as an answer (and even say that you're posting it to distinguish Theravada and Mahayana doctrine)..

Comment: @ChrisW I may consider ur suggestion however the OP is asking from a Theravadist perspective obviously - 28th/ 29th Buddha. I think an answerer should at least knows there are different schools to begin with, though the OP is acceptable to have no such knowledge excused as a questioner - because he doesn't know so he asked.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my personal idea , I believe if the time is infinite, and there  is no starting or ending to the universe, there can be infinite number of Buddhas . 
For your information::,According to teravada they say its 28 buddhas , In mahayana , they say 1000 buddhas .

Answer (score 1):

In the [Mahapadana Sutta](http://buddhasutra.com/files/mahapadana_sutta.htm) of the Digha Nikaya, the Buddha explained some natural laws (dhammata) pertaining to the Bodhisatta Vipassi who arose in the world ninety one aeons ago. In the last 91 Kalpa (Aeons) only 7 Buddha’s have come. After Vipassi Buddha, the other six Buddhas who came were Sikhi, Vessabhu, Kakusanda, Konagamana, Kassapa and the Gautama Buddha.

A Kalpa is like Eternity. So just imagine what 91 kalpa is like. In the Anamatagga-samyutta — The unimaginable beginnings of samsara. In Samyutta ii, Chapter XV, the Buddha used the parables of the hill and mustard-seed for comparison:

> Suppose there was a solid mass, of rock or hill, one yojana (eight miles) wide, one yojana across and one yojana high and every hundred years, a man was to stroke it once with a piece of silk. That mass of rock would be worn away and ended sooner than would an aeon.
>
> Suppose there was a city of iron walls, one yojana in length, one yojana in width, one yojana high and filled with mustard-seeds to the brim. There-from a man was to take out every hundred years a mustard-seed. That great pile of mustard-seed would be emptied and ended sooner than would an aeon.

At the time of the next Buddha, the average lifespan of a human is going to be eighty thousand years. (In the present day it is around 60 -80 years). There will not be any more Buddhas for many a aeon, after the next, as per the scriptures.

There are [28 Buddhas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_named_Buddhas) described in the Buddhavamsa.  Our Gautama Buddha first obtained “niyata vivarana” that he will definitely become a Buddha in the future, from [Buddha Dipankara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABpankara_Buddha), who was the 24th Buddha preceding Buddha Gotama.